# SSL - if someone has public certificate can someone do man in middle attack?

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

There is a concept called certificate pinning in mobile where the developer does not trust any certificate authority but instead stores the public certificate on the mobile device.  If someone were to gain access to the public cert could they do man in the middle attack on my server ? can they not communicate with my https server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If someone were to gain access to the public cert could they do man in the middle attack on my server ?

no. Session key decryption requires a posession of the corresponding private key. This is the key point of the asymmetric cryptography. When you encrypt data with public key, it cannot be decrypted by using this key. Associated private key must be used to decrypt data. As long as you keep your private key in secret, it is secure.

Comment: No is the correct answer, however your explanation isn't true in the case that DHE/ECDHE is used. Here, there is no decryption using the private key. [_p_ and _g_ and _g^a mod p_ are sent to the client, but signed by the private key](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy.html).

Comment: Session keys are not encrypted or even sent and therefore cannot be decrypted or even intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

No. They can't prove that they own the SSL certificate they send unless they have its private key.